# Am I overdoing stuff when I sever interfaces from concrete implementations?

Tags: java, project-structure

I've separated interfaces from their implementations by different packages, it's just add clarity, the separation is good looking and it is easier to navigate the project structure. I like it. The only point which confuses me - I've started thinking I might overdo stuff. So the question is - do you think it's a good practice to split code like that?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to use an interface when only one class will ever implement it?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/159813/do-i-need-to-use-an-interface-when-only-one-class-will-ever-implement-it)

Comment: @gnat I doubt those two questions have something in common

Comment: How are they different?

Comment: @Panzercrisis this one is about project structure, it's not like I'm asking if I need to have those interfaces, of course, I need them. The one gnat pointed to is about a creation of an interface if you have only one implementation.

Comment: You may want to edit the question to use an example where the interfaces are getting reused.

Comment: @Panzercrisis it's evident I wasn't clear with my question, I tried to rephrase it.

Comment: Unrelated:  You implement use cases as interfaces and classes?  Interesting.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is fine, and I do it.

However I would flip it from how you are doing it, the `*impl` on every class would drive me insane. Instead I would name the interfaces differently (`IThing` as I am .Net type) and have them in an Interfaces folder. Then the concrete class (`Thing`) is 'normal' and would not need to live in a concrete class folder, just wherever made sense.

In some cases I then publish the interfaces folder as a `Contracts` package for other things that want to work with my main types.

Comment: I actually prefer `IThing` too, but you may want to consider the consistency tradeoffs. Often, I change my coding style a little bit to keep things looking similar to other programming in my current language, and it may be difficult to avoid seeing other "Foo, FooImpl"s in imported Java code.